# Cómo agregar filas a una tabla a medida que selecciono items en Primefaces?

Tags: primefaces, datatable

mi pregunta es como agregar filas a una tabla a medida que selecciono items de un SelectOneMenu. Los SelectOneMenu están en la misma vista que la tabla, o si puede ser en un panelGrid también me serviría.

Gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: Hola y bienvenida a la comunidad. Existen ciertos lineamientos para realizar preguntas. Te sugiero realizar el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que las conozcas.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español! Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender cómo funcionamos aquí y para recibir la mejor ayuda posible. En tu pregunta nos debes decir que has intentado, que no te ha funcionado, que errores te ha dado, para que podamos considerarla una pregunta válida. Si no lo haces representa que **no has hecho nada** y puedes recibir [votos negativos](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/2874#2874) por ello, y tu pregunta puede quedar [cerrada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) pronto. Gracias por colaborar.